# How to make snap apps use my gtk theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, snap, gtk

Snap now has GTK theming support - wonderful! So I just installed a snap app but when I opened it - it was using the Adwaita theme instead of my default Ubuntu 20.04 Yaru theme.

I looked around and found that I needed to install `gtk-common-themes` so I installed it. But what's next? How do I tell Snap to use Yaru theme?

Comment: People are now packaging GTK and icon themes as Snap apps and putting them on the Snap Store for smooth installation. A variety of popular GTK themes are currently available as 'Snap themes' including Adapta, Orchis, Layan, Mojave, Qogir, Canta, and Vimix. More will likely follow.

Answer (score 3):

Snap apps can only use themes that are packed as snaps. When you use a theme that is included in the `gtk-common-themes` snap, no effort is required from your part. The snap applications will automatically use the matching theme.

More themes also are increasingly available as specific snap packages. The way to activate these themes is, however, quite jarring, as explained on this [OMGBuntu blog post](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/change-snap-app-theme). The site gives the example for the "layan" theme. After installing the snap version of the theme:

```
sudo snap install layan-themes
```

you can enable the theme for each installed snap application with the following onliner:

```
for i in $(snap connections | grep gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes | awk '{print $2}'); do sudo snap connect $i layan-themes:gtk-3-themes; done
```

Comment: Is this still the case in 2023? This is the kind of thing that makes me think why Linux is not becoming a mainstream desktop OS. I can't imagine how the developers of Snap thought this was an acceptable solution for one of the most basic things like using a dark theme when the OS's theme is dark. I mean, even if it was not exactly the same theme as the native one, at least Snap system should have come with two in-built themes (dark/light) and respected the OS's dark/light setting.