# Custom GTK themes for snap applications

Tags: themes, snap, gtk

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 running Gnome and downloaded a custom GTK theme (WhiteSur in this case). It works well with most applications but the theme is not inherited by some snap applications, most notably Firefox, whereas some other snap applications like Spotify do strangely follow the custom theme without issues. I've downloaded the snap version of the WhiteSur theme and tried using the command indicated [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1324914/1613439) to manually edit the snap interface connections but the problem still persists. Running

```
snap connections
```

shows something like

```
Interface               Plug                   Slot                              Notes
content[gtk-3-themes]   firefox:gtk-3-themes   gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes    -
content[gtk-3-themes]   firefox:gtk-3-themes   whitesur-gtk-theme:gtk-3-themes   manual
```

Is such output to be expected and how can I fix my issue?

Comment: We can assume you fully shut down Firefox and restarted it, or logged out then back in before concluding this does not work?

Comment: @vanadium Yes, I have already tried that, unfortunately. I have discovered that Firefox does appear to use the system theme if the title bar is enabled, but I would like to have a solution without resorting to that.

Comment: I see. Without the title bar, you will not manage to get the window buttons of firefox to adopt these from the theme - in the latter case, it is firefox itself that draws these buttons ("client side decorations") - this is not due to Snap. It is because Firefox actually is actually not a GTK application.

Comment: @vanadium Oh, I see. Thanks.